# Return CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value with specific timezone in Spring data JPA/Hibernate (HQL) query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, timestamp, hql

I have an Spring Boot API that uses Spring data JPA (1.5.9)/Hibernate (5.0.12) to query my PostgresQL database that is hosted on AWS as a RDS. It is set to Central Time (CST) I have some HQL (Hibernate) queries that use the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` function, but unfortunately and oddly seems to be returning UTC return values for whenever the HQL queries that use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` run.

*I need a way to simply force* the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the HQL query to be **central time (CST)**. I was trying just querying the DB in pure SQL and something like this worked:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago'
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get that to work in HQL, as IntelliJ/Hibernate throws a compilation error for:

```
<expression> GROUP, HAVING, or ORDER expected, got 'AT'
```

My sample HQL query I am using is:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT customerCoupons FROM CustomerCouponsEntity customerCoupons " 
+ "WHERE customerCoupons.couponCode = :couponCode "
+ "AND customerCoupons.expiredDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP "
+ "AND customerCoupons.startDate <= CURRENT TIMESTAMP "
)

List<CustomerCouponsEntity> findByCouponCode(@Param("couponCode") String couponCode);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have the DB set as CST in AWS, so I didn't even expect this `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to be returning a UTC value (still doesn't make sense to me, unless its somehow using the JDBC driver TimeZone or JVM? I mean, this is a Hibernate query, so its not pure SQL right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my own answer;

I tried setting the timezone in the properties/yaml per this article:
https://moelholm.com/blog/2016/11/09/spring-boot-controlling-timezones-with-hibernate

but it did not work no matter what I tried. I made sure I was on hibernate 5.2.3 or greater and it wouldn't work.

I also tried adding the "AT TIMEZONE" in my HQL query but the code wouldn't compile. I guess even though this is valid SQL it doesn't work with the Hibernate SQL queries i.e.

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago'
```

Anyway, the only thing that seemed to work was:

```
@PostConstruct
  void started() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to set the hibernate timezone in your spring boot properties file. Example:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=YOUR_TIMEZONE
```

Ensure that the value of **YOUR_TIMEZONE** matches your DB timezone.

I guess this [article](https://moelholm.com/blog/2016/11/09/spring-boot-controlling-timezones-with-hibernate) will help

Comment: Ok I was trying that (I should have put that in my original question) but it wasn't working. We have 3+ profiles in my application.yaml, but let me try again Thank you

Comment: when I try adding the jdbc.time_zone = UTC do my Spring data JPA/Hibernate project where all my repository classes are, it seems to have no affect on the "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" function unfortunately.

Comment: Also have you tried setting your preferred timezone in your spring boot application? I guess this will affect the timezone when generating a timestamp using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. ```TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(YOUR_TIMEZONE));```

Comment: I haven't tried that because in the article you linked and everywhere I read, it said , it carries negative drawbacks. I am trying the yaml/properties for the last 2 hours and absolutely cannot get it to work for some reason. I made sure I was on hibernate > 5.2.3 and was putting different variations of the "jdbc.time_zone" etc in my yaml - but nothing worked. I will try setting the time zone in the SpringBoot main method now since I'm running out of ideas -_- Thx for replying

Comment: I assume even though the "AT TIMEZONE 'Americas/Chicago'" works in the pure SQL queries, there is nothing similiar to run in HQL right? because "AT" isnt even an HQL keyword?

Comment: Yeah, I think HQL kinda restrict that. But if you badly need to use TIMEZONE in your query, I guess you can go with Native Queries.